# Tried to apply multiprocessing process in my pipeline but it didn't work at all. Need suggestion to solve it

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to use the multiprocessing library to parallelize the below framework, bcoz currently, it generates output super slow.
As per the rule of multiprocessing to create a new function for the inner loop, I followed that, but still, I am not getting the output. **P never goes to row function**. I don't know why it's not calling above function.
**It's a nested loop problem**.

Here is the code:

```
X_TILES = 120
Y_TILES = 69

    def row(X_TILES, y, tile_SizeX_org, tile_SizeY_org, width, height, rea, stack, encoded_items_org):
        for x in X_TILES:
            tileX_org, tileY_org, eSizeX_org, eSizeY_org = tiles_coordinates(x, y, tile_SizeX_org,tile_SizeY_org, width, height)
            t_org = img_read(rea, stack, tileX_org, tileY_org, eSizeX_org, eSizeY_org)
            encoded_items_org.append(t_org)
    
        return encoded_items_org
    
    
    def tile_size_org(tile_SizeX_org, tile_SizeY_org, width, height, rea, stack):
        nXTiles, nYTiles = num_of_tiles_to_read(width, height, tile_SizeX_org, tile_SizeY_org)
        print(nYTiles, nXTiles)
        X_TILES = range(nXTiles)
        Y_TILES = range(nYTiles)
        encoded_items_org = []
        encoded_items_or = []
        
        for y in Y_TILES:
            p = Process(target=row, args=(X_TILES, y, tile_SizeX_org, tile_SizeY_org, width, height, rea, stack, encoded_items_org))
            encoded_items_or.append(p)
            p.start()
    
        for p in encoded_items_or:
            p.join()
            return encoded_items_or
        ..................................
        ..................................
        ..................................
```

I am passing **p = Process(target=row, args=(X_TILES, y, tile_SizeX_org, tile_SizeY_org, width, height, rea, stack, encoded_items_org))** command to run in a CPU core.
I am confused about whether I am following the correct way to implement the multiprocessing in python.
My laptop is a **12 core** so I am also curious about this step: **for y in Y_TILES**, whether this for loop will run for 69 times or not bcoz I have just 12 core.
I am trying to append each value of encoded_items_org (it append bytes of an image) into the form of a list.
Please, I really need help to solve this problem or some suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Where are you calling `tile_size_org`?

Comment: Is there an error message being generated when you run this code? One possible way debug is to try creating, starting, and joining the process outside of a loop and making sure it works there. Also one potential issue is the return value of the `row` function. The child process won't actually return anything, so `encoded_items_org` will always be empty. You'll have to use a [shared value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in order to access the value of `encoded_items_org` in the parent process.

Comment: @Czaporka, after this one, 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    zstack = 0
    tile_size_org(tile_SizeX_org, tile_SizeY_org, width, height, reader, zstack)

Comment: @RohinDasari, I think you have understood my problem and yes u r right encoded_items_org is always empty. I went through a shared value link but I didn't understand what kind of value should I pass in row function. And one more thing, I didn't receive any error, it's running but it's not utilizing CPU while I check the CPU history (i can it's doing nothing just loaded each process in the memory but it never calls or operates row function).

Comment: @YubrajGupta while some things like `multiprocessing.Pool` do it for you, you *must* use some sort of shared value in order to get any data out of a child process. `return encoded_items_org` at the end of `row()` currently does absolutely nothing. Each child process has its own separate copies of everything, so each `encoded_items_org` is a separate list (which just gets thrown away at the end of the process). I tend to use a `Queue` quite often as it is generally easy to use, and fairly simple to understand what's going on (though it's not very fast of efficient).

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why it's not calling above function

The confusion here is that your `row` function **is** being called, but the return value doesn't go anywhere. Separate processes have separate memory, so when a child process modifies its copy of `encoded_items_org`, it does not modify the "master" copy in the main process. The return value of a function ran in a child process is also ignored completely, so `return encoded_items_org` doesn't help. Since nothing modifies the "master" copy of `encoded_items_org`, it remains an empty list.

In order to get the results from each child process you must use some sort of "shared" value created with the multiprocessing module that is passed as an argument to the function the child process executes. I frequently use a `Queue` to exchange items between child and parent processes, as they are relatively simple to use. A `Queue` uses `Pickle` to convert the items you want to send back and forth to text, as only text can be sent directly between processes (this means the items sent must be pickle-able).

simple example of using a queue: (be sure to read the comments)

```
def row(q, X_TILES, y, tile_SizeX_org, tile_SizeY_org, width, height, rea, stack):
    encoded_items_org = [] #always starts empty in each child anyway, so don't bother passing it as an argument
    for x in X_TILES:
        tileX_org, tileY_org, eSizeX_org, eSizeY_org = tiles_coordinates(x, y, tile_SizeX_org,tile_SizeY_org, width, height)
        t_org = img_read(rea, stack, tileX_org, tileY_org, eSizeX_org, eSizeY_org)
        encoded_items_org.append(t_org)

    q.put(encoded_items_org) #put to shared queue so it isn't thrown away after the process finishes


def tile_size_org(tile_SizeX_org, tile_SizeY_org, width, height, rea, stack):
    nXTiles, nYTiles = num_of_tiles_to_read(width, height, tile_SizeX_org, tile_SizeY_org)
    print(nYTiles, nXTiles)
    X_TILES = range(nXTiles)
    Y_TILES = range(nYTiles)
    encoded_items_org = []
    encoded_items_or = []
    
    q = multiprocessing.Queue() #create a queue to pass to the child processes as an argument
    
    for y in Y_TILES:
        p = Process(target=row, args=(q, X_TILES, y, tile_SizeX_org, tile_SizeY_org, width, height, rea, stack))
        encoded_items_or.append(p)
        p.start()
        
    for _ in Y_TILES: #this only works if each process puts exactly one item to the queue. otherwise you must track how many times to call "get" some other way.
        encoded_items_org += q.get() #you must "get" all items from the queue before the child processes are "join"ed
        
    for p in encoded_items_or:
        p.join()

    return encoded_items_or #this line was previously inside the for loop when it probably shouldn't be. 

if __name__ == "__main__": #make sure you always use this with multiprocessing to actually start your processes
    tile_size_org(...)
```

> whether this for loop will run for 69 times or not

Yes the loop will run `nYTiles` times, and you will create that many child processes. Most computers have hundreds of processes running at any given time, and this is not a problem. The operating system instructs the cpu cores to rapidly switch between them so they all get worked on. More processes does mean more overhead, and more than 12 will not mean more speed, but it will work just fine. The improved efficiency of only using one process per cpu core may or may not be worth the extra code complexity.

Comment: Alternatively, if you really want to use multiprocessing, maybe use `multiprocessing.Pool` to do your iteration. This will allow you to set the number of workers you want to use, which may help manage your CPU resources. The first example on this [page](https://docs.python.org/3/library)/multiprocessing.html#introduction) shows you how to use it.

Comment: @Aaron, Thank you for your comments. I understood what u have written above. I tried your above suggestion but q.put(encoded_items_org) does not append encoded_items_org = [] of 12 lists values (I don't know why). I didn't get any error. It opens the process.py and goes to _bootstrap and get stuck in util._exit_function(). And sometimes it just runs all process but encoded_items_org is empty.

Comment: @Aaron, And here's the full code: 
https://uapt33090-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/ygupta_ua_pt/EQZ4POX69G1LrlT_xK1fWcsBHx9iaZH5i2XvRDuafT1-XA?e=lJRbBT

Comment: This would be very difficult to debug without having access to your specific system. something easy to add that can fix some issues with threads deadlocking is `multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")`. This is already the default for Windows and MacOS however, so it may or may not be terribly useful. My next thought is that `reader` may not be `pickle`-able. Possibly re-create the reader once inside the child process, though I'm not totally sure on this. My last thought is something with using `javabridge` is causing a problem, but I know the least about this.

Comment: Debugging multiprocessing programs is definitely more difficult, so it is often helpful to break the problem down into single process chunks that you can test independently. I would start with `print(encoded_framed_items_org)` right before `q.put(encoded_framed_items_org)` to make sure the computation is happening within the child then worry about getting the result back.

Comment: @Aaron, Yes you are right, it's super difficult to debug multiprocessing, I am debugging since the morning but so far I haven't found the solution. I checked the value of print(encoded_framed_items_org) sometimes it's print the encoded list and sometimes it doesn't (I don't know why it doesn't print) and q.put(encoded_framed_items_org) never take the encoded_framed_items_org list values.

Comment: And sometimes, for y in Y_TILES: loop just run all its iteration and it doesn't do anything further and the painful thing is that I have to delete every process manually from the system monitor (It take 175MB per process). I am running this code in ubuntu 18.04